# Beautiful Soup multiple URLs

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt
import requests

user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.``3945.88 Safari/537.37"
url = "https://www.atlanticcouncil.org/events/?ac-timing=past"
data = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": user_agent})
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, "lxml")

document = Document()

events = soup.find_all("div", class_ = "gta-embed--content gta-event-embed--content")
for event in events:
    event_name = event.find("h3", class_ = "gta-event-embed--title gta-embed--title")
    link = event.find("a")
    try:
        print(event_name.text)
        document.add_paragraph(event_name.text, style='List Bullet')
        print(link['href'])
        document.add_paragraph(link['href'])
    except:
        continue

document.save('demo.docx')
```

URL1 = https://www.atlanticcouncil.org/events/?ac-timing=past&ac-page=1
URL2 = https://www.atlanticcouncil.org/events/?ac-timing=past&ac-page=2

I tried this but couldn't make it, is this wrong:

```
page = 1
while page != 6:
      url = f"https://www.atlanticcouncil.org/events/?ac-timing=past&ac-page={page}"
      print(url)
      page = page + 1
```

Comment: In your second block of code, instead of using a `while` loop, just use `for page in range(1,7):`

Comment: @MattDmo, thanks! I did this, but when I run the code there were only links like that:
https://www.bookdepository.com/bestsellers?page=1
https://www.bookdepository.com/bestsellers?page=2
https://www.bookdepository.com/bestsellers?page=3
https://www.bookdepository.com/bestsellers?page=4
https://www.bookdepository.com/bestsellers?page=5
https://www.bookdepository.com/bestsellers?page=6

Comment: Isn't that what you were looking for? Those links work for me.

Comment: @MattDMo actually I'm trying to scrap those URLs. I can scrap page one, but I want page two as well. but it just prints the URLs themselves.

Comment: Well right, that's what the code says to do. Once you have your URL constructed, you need to scrape it. I'll write up an answer for you.

Comment: @MattDMo that would be awesome! really appreciated it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt
import requests

user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.``3945.88 Safari/537.37"

def scrape_and_write_to_docx(page):
    url = f"https://www.atlanticcouncil.org/events/?ac-timing=past&ac-page={page}"
    data = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": user_agent})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, "lxml")
    events = soup.find_all("div", class_ = "gta-embed--content gta-event-embed--content")
    for event in events:
        event_name = event.find("h3", class_ = "gta-event-embed--title gta-embed--title")
        link = event.find("a")
        try:
            print(event_name.text)
            document.add_paragraph(event_name.text, style='List Bullet')
            print(link['href'])
            document.add_paragraph(link['href'])
        except:
            continue

document = Document()

for page in range(1,7):
    scrape_and_write_to_docx(str(page))

document.save('demo.docx')
```

Mostly what I did was rearrange things. I took the actual scraping and processing code and put it into a function, then created a quick `for` loop to run through pages 1-6, and called the function with each value of `page`. I opened the new `Document()` at the beginning, and closed/saved it at the very end.

You'll need to do a little tweaking of the strings you write, as the resulting document doesn't look that great, but it has all the info you're looking for.